# How to exclude parts of the app from the shipping binary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If you have an iphone app with demo pages (code/images) that you would want to exclude from the shipping binary, how would you disable them without removing them from the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, select the target (not the project but the target). In the tab "Build Phases" open the list of "compile sources" and any file you don't want to compile for the project can be removed selecting it and then pushing delete key. The same for any resource file (xib, png, ...) opening "Copy Boundle Resources".

Remember you have to to write the code so it can be compiled without the sources not included for this version.

The files (sources and resources) will continue as part of the project as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You would use different "targets" in Xcode. You can then select f.e. "Target membership" for the files and use preprocessor defines for conditional compilation.